# Smoothly moving SVG element on event from current position to a given point

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I'd like to move an SVG element (`image`) slowly from its current position (wherever it is) to a given point when an event is handled.

Since I don't know what the position is, I cannot prepare CSS animation based on keyframes.

So I tried doing the task via DOM manipulating:

```
var curX = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('x'));
var curY = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('y')); // Not used yet.
var curOpacity = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('opacity')); // Not used yet.

var animation = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'animate');
animation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'x');
animation.setAttribute('from', curX);
animation.setAttribute('to', 0); // Move the image to the left border.
animation.setAttribute('dur', '2s'); // '3s', '5s'
animation.setAttribute('repeatCount', 1);

image.appendChild(animation);
```

If I set duration to 3s or 5s, it starts moving as soon as the `animate` element is appended, but when the animation is over the image is returned to the original position. (As I understand this is by design, but I'd like the image to keep its new position).

The second problem is when I set duration to 2s or less, the image stops moving smoothly, it just flickers to the left border and back (I don't know why).

Maybe, there is a better approach?

**UPDATE**

As it's answered below, the image keeps its position if `fill` is set to `freeze`. To reproduce the second problem it is enough to set timeout:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" class="inline-block mb-1">
    <image href="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image/mdn_logo_only_color.png"
        height="200" width="200" x="200" y="200"/>

    <script>
        // <![CDATA[
        var startAnimation = function ()
        {
            const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

            var image = document.querySelector('image');
            var curX = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('x'));
            var curY = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('y')); // Not used yet.
            var curOpacity = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('opacity')); // Not used yet.

            var animation = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'animate');
            animation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'x');
            animation.setAttribute('from', curX);
            animation.setAttribute('to', 0); // Move the image to the left border.
            animation.setAttribute('dur', '2s'); // '3s', '5s'
            animation.setAttribute('repeatCount', 1);
            animation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');

            image.appendChild(animation);
        };
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => window.setTimeout(startAnimation, 1000));
        // ]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```

The image initially twitches and starts moving smoothly only after a half of the way. Chrome 102, x64. As for my computer performance, an animation based on `window.requestAnimationFrame` works with no glitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the 'fill' attribute of your animation:

```
 animation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');
```

See [here (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill#animate) for more details.

As for the jumpy animation behaviour, it hasn't happened in my tests, neither in the live example below nor on a standalone file.

**Live example**

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" class="inline-block mb-1">
  <image href="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="200" width="200" x="200" y="200"/>
  
  <script>
      // <![CDATA[
        document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        
            var image = document.querySelector('image');
            var curX = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('x'));
            var curY = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('y')); // Not used yet.
            var curOpacity = parseFloat(image.getAttribute('opacity')); // Not used yet.

            var animation = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'animate');
            animation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'x');
            animation.setAttribute('from', curX);
            animation.setAttribute('to', 0); // Move the image to the left border.
            animation.setAttribute('dur', '2s'); // '3s', '5s'
            animation.setAttribute('repeatCount', 1);
            animation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');

            image.appendChild(animation);
        });
      // ]]>
  </script>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

The OP's bumpy animation problem when starting the animation through a timeout callback can be remedied by setting the animation element's `begin` attribute to the timeout delay:

```
 animation.setAttribute('begin', '1s');
```

Comment: Thank you, @collapsar! Setting `fill` to `freeze` helped solving the first problem. Now I'm trying to get a minimal reproducible demo for the second. But if there is something like assigning a class with `transition` and then setting `x` and `y` of an SVG element (instead of `left` and `top` for an HTML element), that would be much better. As far as I understand, `x` property isn't animated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: I slightly modified the example and added it to the question (sorry, I don't know how to convert it to a code snippet). If the animation is started after a timeout, the image twitches.

Comment: Check out the last edit to your question to learn how to turn code section into a live snippet. I see th ephenonemon but as of now do not have an idea on how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! It somehow helped (even for duration 1s) though I have no idea why. It also works for combining X and Y animations.